# Strange behaviour on a dictionary

Tags: python

I have to go through a list of 18 names (Peter, Marta, Floyd, etc).  Also, inside of this loop there is another loop on a list that has these type of values: ID, type1, type2, like this:

```
  ID      Type1  Type2
['343', ['Peter', ]]
['135', [, 'Marta']]
['776', [, 'Marta']]
['867', ['Floyd', ]]
['682', [ ,'Floyd']]
['312', ['Floyd', 'Berta']]
```

So, if the type1 matches the outer name, the corresponding ID will be added to a list1, if the type2 matches the outer name, the ID will be added to the list2.

So, at the end I should have this dictionary:

```
"Peter":('343')(),
"Marta":()('135', '776'),
"Floyd":('867', '312')('682')
"Berta":()('312')
```

So, whenever I use any of the keys of this dictionary I will get the two lists of IDs.

My idea is to iterate through the internal list and prepare dynamically list1 and list2, then add it to the dictionary with the key from the outer loop.

```
for j in listofNames:
   listTipe1.clear()
   listTipe2.clear()
   
   for x in listSplit:#has ID, type1, type2
      if (x[1][0]) == j:
         print("Name matches type1, adding its ID to list1")
         listTipe1.append(x[0])
      if (x[1][1]) == j:
         print("Name matches type2, adding its ID to list2")
         listTipe2.append(x[0])
         
   print("Gonna add the key and list1 and list2 of:: " + j)
   name_per_tipe[j] = (listTipe1,listTipe2)
```

At the end I am going through all the elements in the dictionary and finding that all the names have the same list of values.

Can´t figure out what is wrong with this. I placed printing lines for debugging, and I see the first key and IDs gets generated well and added to the dictionary, but from the second name on the list of values 1 and 2 will be added to the existing keys, replacing the values previously assigned for that name.

Comment: `"Peter":('343')(),` makes no sense. Do you mean `"Peter":[('343')()],`?

Comment: "At the end I am going through all the elements in the dictionary and finding that all the names have the same list of values." Of *course*, you keep putting *the same lists in the dictionary*: `name_per_tipe[j] = (listTipe1,listTipe2)`

Comment: Don't clear the lists, create new lists: `listTipe1 = []`

Comment: But the list is getting cleared

Comment: Clearing the list doesn't make a copy, it just removes everything from the list.

Comment: Changed;

   listTipe1.clear()
   listTipe2.clear()
   
for:

   listTipe1 = []
   listTipe2 = [] 
   
That solved the issue.  Thanks!